# install crashdump on ubuntu 1404

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I am following [[here](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html)] to install `crash dump` on Ubuntu 1404:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-crashdump
```

However, it throws exception as below:

```
... unmet dependencies
linux-crashdump  : Depends: kdumptools but it is not going to be installed
```

PS: I have followed [[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)] to solve the problem, but it does not find any broken held package...

Update: my platform is Ubuntu 14.04 on Linux 3.16.0-generic.

Update 2: the following is the complete printout

```
app> sudo apt-get install linux-crashdump kdump-tools makedumpfile libdw1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libdw1 : Depends: libelf1 (= 0.158-0ubuntu5) but 0.158-0ubuntu5.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: did you try `sudo apt-get install kdump-tools`?

Comment: yes, same thing. It will eventually bring me to `libelf1` by saying two versions conflict...

Comment: can you add the complete error to your question?

Comment: @Ron updated as above

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy libelf1`? I think you need to run a package upgrade first: `sudo apt-get upgrade -f libelf1`

Answer (score -2):

run `sudo apt-get update` first.

then [don't run this if you didn't want to upgrade the release ] `sudo do-release-upgrade` for updating the package.
`reboot`.

then run `sudo apt-get install linux-crashdump`

on ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: Is the OP trying to upgrade OP's Ubuntu version?